# Is there an inherent race-condition in the use of IClassFactory::LockServer()?

Tags: com, race-condition

My understanding is that the point of IClassFactory::LockServer() is that having a live IClassFactory instance for a given COM server does not prevent the server from getting unloaded in some situations.

Given that, is there anything that prevents the server from being unloaded between the time CoGetClassObject() returns, and the time at which you call LockServer()? This seems like a race condition to me, but I haven't been able to find anything about it from a cursory google search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CoGetClassObject` returns you `IClassFactory` interface pointer.

With an in-process server your holding this pointer already keeps server from unloading. The `Lock` method addresses the problem of loading/unloading/reloading of the library after you released all outstanding interfaces (including `IClassFactory` pointer in question!) and before next instance creation request emerges.

Out-of-process servers create and publish their class factories on their own and their class factories do not affect lock state of the server. That is, your obtaining, referencing, releasing a class factory interface pointer should not normally affect the lock state of the server (unlike the `Lock` method). This suggests that holding a `IClassFactory` interface pointer before creating actual instance might keep the server in unloadable state, so that at the time of `CreateInstance` call the server is already gone. This is where, however, COM API is helping to keep server alive.

In case of out-of-proc server, your client interface pointer references on the `IClassFactory` interface pointer cause an automatic `IClassFactory::LockServer` call provided by class factory marshaler. In a different way but it is still true: a client holding valid `IClassFactory` interface pointer prevents server from unloading.

Comment: I see. Seems like they could have just required you to keep an IClassFactory instance alive, would have been simpler. Don't know where I read that IClassFactory instances 'didn't count'.

Comment: Clients don't normally deal with `IClassFactory` directly, instead they use APIs like `CoCreateInstance` which use class factory pointer internally and release after use. `Lock` method gives a longer lock.

Comment: Ahh, but it's not like you can call `LockServer` if you're using something like `CoCreateInstance` anyway.

Comment: If I recall correctly, a class factory doesn't normally keep an out-of-proc server running. Otherwise, it would never shut down - it calls `CoRegisterClassObject` first thing, which holds a strong reference on the class factory. So if the client wants to hold on to `IClassFactory*` pointer, it has to call `LockServer` to prevent the server from unloading - just `AddRef`ing the pointer is not enough. For in-proc-server, calling `LockServer` is unnecessary but harmless; just keeping an `AddRef`ed `IClassFactory*` pointer is sufficient.

Comment: I just took a look at my copy of 'Inside COM', and it says basically what Igor did, so that's where I got that idea. If he and the book are correct, then my question stands.

Comment: If I recall correctly, "Inside COM" (or another book in that vein) does discuss a race condition inherent in COM server activation. This is one of the reasons why a typical out-of-proc server keeps running for a few seconds after the last lock or reference is released. It's still possible for a client to call `CoCreateInstance` at just the wrong time - just as the server decides that enough time has passed and it's OK to shut down - but it would require a rather extraordinary coincidence.

Comment: See update above: client's `IClassFactory` is still sufficient to keep server running through automatic `LockServer` call provided by COM API (class factory proxy/stub pair).